# How to get previous date in odoo xml

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

```
<span t-esc="context_timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')"/>
```

I want to display previous date from the current date in report.Please help.

Comment: Can you put this question as resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
<span t-esc="context_timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days = 1)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')"/>
```